# Xcode 8: custom class based on generic class not available in storyboard

Tags: swift, ios10, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

I just converted my codes to Swift3 with Xcode8. Here are two simplified classes. The first one is a generic class as base:

```
class MyBaseTVController<T: NSManagedObject>: 
   UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
...
}
```

the second one is a custom class based on above one:

```
class MyTVController : MyBaseTVController<MyEntity> {
   ...
}
```

The problem I have is that the MyTVController class is not available in storyboard (as in Identity Inspector tab, custom class).

[image]

Further investigation, I found one thing interesting. If I drop the generic type from the base class, MyTVController is showing up in the storyboard.

I do need to define the base class with a generic type. Is there anyway to make my inherited class available in storyboard? If not, any way I can do it in code?

Comment: It seems that this may be bug in the current Xcode 8. See Apple Developer Forums discussion [Xcode 8 - Problem with View Controllers initialized in storyboard](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50309)